# PHP files for users

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand a concept that I've been trying to learn the last couple days;

I see many social networks using the user's id in the url after the file (Example: "Socialnetwork.php?id=123") to navigate to a certain user.

I want to make `profile.php` do the same thing instead of directing me to my homepage everytime.

QUESTION: How can I use the user's id in my database to read out unique profile data for them in a single file? - Furthermore, what should I add to my `register_config.php` file to allow this?

```
    <?php

//REQUIRING PASS API CONFIG
require 'password_config.php';
require 'connect.php';
    //VARIABLES FOR POST DATA               //OTHER VARIABLES
    $email = $_POST['register_email'];  
    $username = $_POST['register_username'];        $userlen = strlen($username);
    $password = $_POST['register_password'];        $passlen = strlen($password);
    $submit = $_POST['register_submit'];            $hash_password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $query2 = mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows_email = mysql_num_rows($query2); 

    $query3 = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $query4 = mysql_query($query3);
    $num_rows_username = mysql_num_rows($query4);


if(isset($submit))
{
    $errors = array();

    if( $password == $username )
    {
        $errors[] = '-Same Username and Pass. ';
    }
    elseif( $userlen < 8 )
    {
        $errors[] = '-Username must be atleast 8 characters. ';
    }  
    elseif( $userlen > 32 )
    {
        $errors[] = '-Username must only contain 32 characters. ';
    }
    elseif( empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($email) )
    {
        $errors[] = '-Please do not leave fields empty. ';
    }
    elseif( $passlen < 8 )
    {
        $errors[] = '-Password must be atleast 8 characters. ';
    }  
    elseif( $passlen > 32 )
    {
        $errors[] = '-Password must only contain 32 characters. ';
    }
    elseif( $num_rows_email != 0 )
    {
        $errors[] = 'Email already exists';
    }
    elseif( $num_rows_username != 0 )
    {
        $errors[] = 'Username already exists';
    }

    //IF THERE ARE NO ERRORS
    if (count($errors) == 0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $insertUser = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES ('$email','$username','$hash_password')";
        mysql_query($insertUser);

           //trying things I have found, but didnt work
           $getUID = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
           $results = mysql_query($getUID);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        $uid = $row['id'];
        if(!file_exists("user/$uid")){mkdir("user/$uid", 0755);}
        }

        mail($email,'Welcome','Welcome to the site');
        header('Location: ../new_account.php');
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

NOTE: -I KNOW I DID NOT CLEAN POST DATA.

`PROFILE.PHP` CODE:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require 'include/connect.php';
if(!$_SESSION['key']){die('no key');}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$uid'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$user = $row['username'];
}
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Profile</title>
      <link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
   </head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
      <?php require 'include/header.php'; ?>
      <?= 'NJM ID # ==>'.$_SESSION['uid'].'<br />'.'Username ==>'.$user; ?>

      <br />
   <p>Try our beta mode<a href='forum/forum.php'> forum</a></p>
      <br />
   <p><a href='find_friends.php'>Find Friends</a></p>   
      <br />
   <p><a href='index.php'>Home</a></p>
   <?php require 'include/footer.php'; ?>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the same script? Use a separate `profile.php` script for this.

Comment: I had initially thought that I had to make a file in regards to the user id, I will post my profile.php code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts of the URL you refer to are known as `GET` parameters. You can access them in PHP via `$_GET`.

For example the URL you specified has an `id` parameter, so in PHP you could get the value of this with `$_GET['id']`.

In your situation if you wanted to load a user's information via their ID you would take the value from `$_GET['id']` and assign it to a variable e.g. `$id`.

Then in the `WHERE` clause of your database query you would specify something like `WHERE id = $id` to make use of this.

This technique assumes that you have an ID as a primary key or similar that you can reference in your `users` table.

**Please note** `GET` parameters are especially susceptible to SQL injection since it's easy to supply values into them. You must sanitise and validate all input. Ideally you might want to look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements to bind any inputs into queries to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: So in doing this, should my registration form be using the GET method instead of POST?

Comment: @EugeneStamp No your registration form is fine and doesn't need anything changed. For what you want create a new file called `profile.php` or similar which will use the `$_GET` parameter to get the ID you will use to execute queries and get the data you want to display.

Comment: Ok, perfect, one last question; How would I actually implement the $_GET parameter in `profile.php`? I have also added the code for `profile.php` in the question.

Comment: Just put something like: `$uid = $_GET['id']` before your SQL query and then the value of `$uid` would be e.g. 4 if you had `profile.php?id=4` as your URL. You'll probably want to use `isset` to check that an ID has been supplied so that you can handle that situation e.g. display an error or something.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much sir.